# Typing a redirect HOC in TypeScript with Next.js

Tags: typescript, next.js, typescript-typings, react-props, higher-order-components

I'm building a Next.js project with TypeScript. I'm trying to type a HOC that redirects the user based on the Redux state.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import { RootState } from 'client/redux/root-reducer';
import Router from 'next/router.js';
import { curry } from 'ramda';
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedProps } from 'react-redux';

import hoistStatics from './hoist-statics';

function redirect(predicate: (state: RootState) => boolean, path: string) {
  const isExternal = path.startsWith('http');

  const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    shouldRedirect: predicate(state),
  });

  const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);

  return hoistStatics(function <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    function Redirect({
      shouldRedirect,
      ...props
    }: T & ConnectedProps<typeof connector>): JSX.Element {
      useEffect(() => {
        if (shouldRedirect) {
          if (isExternal && window) {
            window.location.assign(path);
          } else {
            Router.push(path);
          }
        }
      }, [shouldRedirect]);

      return <Component {...props} />;
    }

    return Redirect;
  });
}

export default curry(redirect);
```

I feel like I'm being close, but can't quite make sense of the last error. `<Component {...props} />` yells:

```
Type 'Pick<T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, "dispatch" | Exclude<keyof T, "shouldRedirect">>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Pick<T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, "dispatch" | Exclude<keyof T, "shouldRedirect">>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Pick<T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, "dispatch" | Exclude<keyof T, "shouldRedirect">>'.
```

What is going on here? I can make the code pass by typing the inner HOC like this:

```
return hoistStatics(function <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
  function Redirect(
    props: T & ConnectedProps<typeof connector>,
  ): JSX.Element {
    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.shouldRedirect) {
        if (isExternal && window) {
          window.location.assign(path);
        } else {
          Router.push(path);
        }
      }
    }, [props.shouldRedirect]);

    return <Component {...props} />;
  }

  return Redirect;
});
```

But that would mean that `Component` gets a prop called `shouldRedirect` which it shouldn't. It should just receive and pass on the props it usually receives.

I had to disable two warnings.

```
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  return hoistStatics(function <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
```

And

```
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    return connector(Redirect);
```

`hoistStatics` is a higher-order HOC and looks like this.

```
import hoistNonReactStatics from 'hoist-non-react-statics';

const hoistStatics = (
  higherOrderComponent: <T>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<T>,
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  ) => (props: T & any) => JSX.Element,
) => (BaseComponent: React.ComponentType) => {
  const NewComponent = higherOrderComponent(BaseComponent);
  hoistNonReactStatics(NewComponent, BaseComponent);
  return NewComponent;
};

export default hoistStatics;
```

Its types are also hacked together (as you can see in the disabled warning).

How can you type these two functions?

**EDIT:**

After Linda's help `hoistStatics` works now. `Redirect` still causes problems though. [I asked a new question for this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65966068/telling-typescript-that-t-should-be-allowed-to-be-instantiated-with-an-arbitrary).

```
function redirect(predicate: (state: RootState) => boolean, path: string) {
  const isExternal = path.startsWith('http');

  const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    shouldRedirect: predicate(state),
  });

  const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);

  return hoistStatics(function <T>(
    Component: React.ComponentType<Omit<T, 'shouldRedirect'>>,
  ) {
    function Redirect({
      shouldRedirect,
      ...props
    }: T & ConnectedProps<typeof connector>): JSX.Element {
      useEffect(() => {
        if (shouldRedirect) {
          if (isExternal && window) {
            window.location.assign(path);
          } else {
            Router.push(path);
          }
        }
      }, [shouldRedirect]);

      return <Component {...props} />;
    }

    return connector(Redirect);
  });
}
```

The line with `connector(Redirect)` still is throwing errors:

```
Argument of type '({ shouldRedirect, ...props }: T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<Matching<{ shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>>>'.
  Type '({ shouldRedirect, ...props }: T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>) => Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Matching<{ shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>>>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<{ shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>>>' is not assignable to type 'T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>'.
        Type 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<{ shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>>>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
          'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'PropsWithChildren<Matching<{ shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>, T & { shouldRedirect: boolean; } & DispatchProp<AnyAction>>>'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Error

Typescript can have give errors when piecing together props from various spread operations because of edge cases which would lead to an invalid object.

```
return hoistStatics(function <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<T>) {
    function Redirect({
      shouldRedirect,
      ...props
    }: T & ConnectedProps<typeof connector>): JSX.Element {
         /*...*/
      return <Component {...props} />;
    }
```

The component props `T` can be any object.  The edge case that breaks this is if `T` includes a required property `shouldRedirect`.

We destructured `shouldRedirect` away from the props when we wrote `{shouldRedirect, ...props}`.  Therefore know that this `props` variable cannot possibly contain a variable `shouldRedirect`.  It is type `Omit<T, 'shouldRedirect'>`.  If we are in that edge case scenario where `T` has a required `shouldRedirect` prop, then we have a problem here: `<Component {...props} />` because `props` would not fulfill the requirement of `T`.

The error you got is hard to read because the type that it outputs is so long-winded, but that type represents the `props` object.  "'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type" basically means that these props might fulfill `T` or they might not fulfill `T`, depending on what `T` is.

### The Solution

This comes up a lot when writing HOCs and you can always resort to `{...props as T}` if it comes down to it.  Often what I do is to pass the entire object like what you've done in your "I can make the code pass" code block.  If we want to drop the undesired properties and keep it type-safe, we need to disallow the bad edge case. We keep `T` vague but state that our `Component` cannot require this prop by using `Omit`.

```
function <T>(Component: React.ComponentType<Omit<T, 'shouldRedirect'>>)
```

### Typing hoistStatics

`hoistStatics` is a function which takes an HOC and returns an HOC.  We know that an HOC can manipulate props such that the props of the composed component (`Outer`) are different from those of the base component (`Inner`).  So we can use two generics here.  Whatever those two types are, `hoistStatics` should not change them and should return an HOC with the same signature as its argument.

We define a generalized `HOC` signature to keep things clean

```
type HOC<Inner, Outer = Inner> = (
  Component: React.ComponentType<Inner>,
) => React.ComponentType<Outer>
```

Then we use that type to describe `hoistStatics`

```
const hoistStatics = <I, O>(
  higherOrderComponent: HOC<I, O>
): HOC<I, O> => (BaseComponent: React.ComponentType<I>) => {
  const NewComponent = higherOrderComponent(BaseComponent);
  hoistNonReactStatics(NewComponent, BaseComponent);
  return NewComponent;
};
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! `hoistStatics` works perfectly. I amended my question with the new error coming from `Redirect`. Would super appreciate if you could help me resolve that, too.

Comment: I have to look into the details of the typings for `InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps`, `Matching`, etc from the react-redux typings.

Comment: I'll just accept your answer and give you your bounty and open a new question. If you have another look, thank you very much! If not, you already helped me sooo much! 