# Per-page layout for pages wrapped with HOC using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, layout, next.js, higher-order-components

I want to apply layout to a page like the below link:

[layouts#per-page-layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/layouts#per-page-layouts)

But my page has a difference, it's wrapped with a HOC, so I applied `getLayout` to the higher order component itself like this:

```
PageWithAuth.getLayout
```

But it gives me this error:

[image]

The page looks like this:

```
function TestPage() {
  return {
    /** Your content */
  }
}

const PageWithAuth = withAuth(TestPage);

PageWithAuth.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
  return (
      <Layout>{page}</Layout>
  )
}

export default PageWithAuth;
```

`_app.tsx` looks like this:

```
type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)
}
```

HOC looks like this:

```
export function withAuth<P>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) {
  const ComponentWithAuth = (props: P) => {
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };
  return ComponentWithAuth;
}
```

How to solve it?

Comment: I believe the getLayout typing is getting lost in your HOC.  Your HOC should take the props as generics and return them - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65893770/15304814  - Also, you can simplify a bit by using the React's type FC for your getLayout.  { Component : { getLayout: FC }} & AppProps

Comment: Where does `withAuth` come from?

Comment: @juliomalves what do you mean? its inside a simple tsx file, I removed actual codes and simplified it here, but its job is redirect users to login page if user is not logged In, you can see sample project here [link](https://github.com/dev-bahar/testlayout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly type the return type of `withAuth` by extending `React.FunctionComponent`, and adding the `getLayout` property to it.

```
type WithAuthComponent<P> = React.FunctionComponent<P> & {
    getLayout?: (page: React.ReactElement) => React.ReactNode
}

export function withAuth<P = {}>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>): WithAuthComponent<P> {
    const ComponentWithAuth = (props: P) => {
        // Your auth logic
        return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }
    return ComponentWithAuth
}
```